# libGDX - endless loop in Box2D world step

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm working on a little game with [libGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), that uses [Box2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) for collision detection. This was working fine, till I added an *arrow* to the game, so the player can *shoot*. Since I added this feature I'm facing the problem that the game gets stuck from time to time, and doesn't react anymore.

I think the reason for this behaviour is an **endless loop** somewhere in the **Box2D world step**. When I stop the execution using the debugger the stopping point is always in the `World.step(float, int, int)` method. Unfortunately this is a **native method** so I can't find where the problem is exactly:

```
// from com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World

public void step (float timeStep, int velocityIterations, int positionIterations) {
    jniStep(addr, timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
}

private native void jniStep (long addr, float timeStep, int velocityIterations, int positionIterations);
```

---

**The problem:**

Sometimes when using the new *"shoot arrow"* feature the **execution seems to stop and the game just freezes**. It is realy hard to reproduce, therefore I can't realy tell what the real root cause is. It only appears when adding a new *arrow* to the Box2D world, but the problem does not appear all the time.

---

**What I've tried so far:**

- To validate that the problem is within the Box2D code, I've tried to change the *mask* of the *arrow's* fixture to `0x0000`, so it doesn't collide with any other object. This actually fixed the problem (or at least I couldn't reproduce it anymore). But this doesn't help very much, because an arrow that doesn't hit anything isn't very usefull in the game...
- Changing the *mask* of the fixture, so it doesn't collide with a specific category (called `CATEGORY_OBSTACLE`) also seemed to fix the problem, but I have no idea why, and still this isn't realy a solution...

---

**The code:**

Since I couldn't seem to even reliably reproduce the problem, I also wasn't able to create a *minimal reproducable example*. I can only point to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tfassbender/DwarfScrollerGDX) of the game. Sorry for this :( The current code is placed in the branch [projectile_bug](https://github.com/tfassbender/DwarfScrollerGDX/tree/projectile_bug).

To explain the code a bit:

- The class `GameScreen` has a `render` method, from which the `World.step` method is called (the one that causes the endless loop).
- The class `Dwarf` has an `executeSpecialAction` method, which starts the creation of the *arrow* through some factory methods.
- In the end, the class `ProjectileFactory` has a `createProjectile` method, that creates the *arrow* and adds it to the world.
- The *categories* and *masks* that are used by the Box2D fixtures are placed in the `PhysicsBodyCategories` class. The *arrow's* fixture uses the  mask `MASK_PLAYER_ATTACK`

---

**Steps to reproduce:**

Since I don't realy know the root cause of the problem, the bug can only be reproduced by shooting some arrows over the map:

- Start the game using the **main method** in the class `DesktopLauncher` in the `desktop`-subproject.
- Move over the world and fire some *arrows* using the **space key**
- Hope for the bug to appear... It usually takes quite some arrows on the world for the bug to appear (I increased the fire rate in the [projectile_bug](https://github.com/tfassbender/DwarfScrollerGDX/tree/projectile_bug) branch to speed things up a bit)

---

**The Question:**

I'm not sure what causes this bug and I'm still quite new to Box2D. If anyone has an idea on how to fix this or knows a workarround for this problem, it would realy help me a lot. Also if you know about some related, reported bugs or anything like this, it could also help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Line 905, https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/src/dynamics/b2_world.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I bite for it. In my experience box2d crashes or hangs most of the time when bodies or fixtures are not correctly destroyed, or when there are some dangling references to destroyed bodies. So I just tried to remove this statement form your code `PhysicsWorld.getInstance().removeBodiesAndFixtures();` right after the step function, and voila, it works. Nice game btw. This is of course not the solution, but it might give you a hint where to search for the root cause.

Comment: After some trial and error the solution seemed to be to always set the reference to the `body` to `null` after removing it from the world. This seems to prevent some undefined behaviour like mentioned in the [Box2D documentation](https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_loose_ends.html#Implicit%20Destruction). So the problem indeed was **caused by removing the bodies from the world**. Thank your very much for the hint. It realy helped a lot :)